# subscriber callback

Tags: ros, subscribe, callback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I am using a subscriber with a callback. It works fine for a while but then the program suddenly stops. My process does not die but stops/freezes.

This is what I do ...

> sub = nh.subscribe("topic_name",
> 10000, &Callback, this);

ros::spinOnce();

I operate two robots with the same code and most of the time one stops receiving data from the callback. The other one proceeds as suggested. I realized that the subscribing works but the process freezes during the spinOnce().

Does anyone have an idea?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/156616/subscriber-callback/) by [dneuhold](https://answers.ros.org/users/5295/dneuhold/) on ROS Answers with karma: 205 on 2014-04-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are only using `spinOnce`. This will only handle messages once. If you want to continuously receive messages call this in a loop or use `ros::spin`.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dneuhold](https://answers.ros.org/users/5295/dneuhold/) on 2014-04-23**:
I just need to receive messages once at this position. The strange part is that the program stops/freezes after executing the nh.subscribe.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-04-23**:
Can you try setting the queue size to 1.